# Getting InvalidInput error when invoking Tokens API in Selling Partner API for Direct Fulfillment Orders

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to invoke the Direct Fulfilment Orders API for the operations but not able to call

getOrders (https://sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/vendor/directFulfillment/orders/v1/purchaseOrders?createdAfter=XXXX&MarketplaceIds=XXXX)
submitAcknowledgement (https://sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/vendor/directFulfillment/orders/v1/acknowledgements)
when i done an investigation it came into my consideration that as it is restricted operation so need to get RDT from Tokens API using LWA and AWS STS Token.

I tried to invoke the tokens API in sandbox with the below POST request in body and LWA token in header and STS token in Authorization but getting below mentioned error.

Request Body:

```
{
"restrictedResources": [
{
"method": "GET",
"path": "vendor/directFulfillment/orders/v1/purchaseOrders"
}
],
"targetApplication": "amz1.sellerapps.app.target-application"
}`
```

Response Body:

```
`{
"errors": [
{
"code": "InvalidInput",
"message": "Could not match input arguments",
"details": ""
}
]
}`
```

Can some please help me here for below points:

1- what mistake I am doing here and why it is giving me an error
2- I have configured IAM User, IAM Role, IAM Policy and defined the Developer Profile and created app and self-authorized it with the seller account. Is it ok or do i need to with some other account type (Vendor Central).
3- Further to get RDT from Token API for Direct Fulfillment Purchase order API the request body mentioned above is ok or what is wrong with this request.
4- Can someone please guide me to get the correct request payload for POST method in Token API to get RDT. I have gone through documentation and issue posted on community but unable to find the correct one.

Your swift response and help in this regards will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Regards,
Bilal Ahmed Munir

Request

```
`{
  "restrictedResources": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "vendor/directFulfillment/orders/v1/purchaseOrders"
    }
  ],
  "targetApplication": "amzn1.sellerapps.app.target-application"
}`
```

Error Response:

```
`{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "InvalidInput",
            "message": "Could not match input arguments",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are trying to get an RDT token for restricted operation and remove this "targetApplication": "amzn1.sellerapps.app.target-application".